# Missing files that have not yet been commited and pushed

Tags: github, github-actions

Hello I'm trying to test my actions locally using https://github.com/nektos/act

But the problem is when I want to use some of the files that have not yet been committed and pushed to the remote, act says that these files don't exist.
How to solve it? Below is my action config.

As you can seen in first step I'm doing a checkout to actions@v3. Without this, the next step shows nothing, but when I do checkout then it seems that my local sources are not get into consideration.

```
name: Main

on: [push, workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  terffere:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - id: ls
        run: ls -la ./.github/workflows
        shell: bash
```

Comment: do you have already tried to skip that step? Like https://github.com/nektos/act#skipping-steps

Comment: I've probably found what was the problem... My action file was in .github/workflows/build directory. At the same time, in my .gitignore I've got entry saying that build directories should be ignored...When I changed the name of this directory, when I use actions/checkout@v3 I can see my local changes, including file from this particular directory